# ¿Cómo hacer "sesiones" en golang como en php?

Tags: go, sesiones

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una sitio web con golang actualmente, y quiero implementar un sistema como las sesiones en php, es decir, tener variables que esten en todas partes del servidor, y que el cliente no tenga acceso a ellas a diferencia de las cookies, pero no se como hacerlo. He intentado buscar alguna forma de hacer algo similar, pero la mayoría de soluciones tenian fallas en varios aspectos, como problemas cuando se usa mas de un servidor o cosas por el estilo. Ahora que expliqué lo que me gustaría hacer, ¿hay algun paquete en golang que haga esto o conocen alguna forma de hacer algo como eso? Desde ahora gracias :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer lo que dices, pienso que depende mucho de que librería o framework web uses.

Por ejemplo si usas [echo](https://echo.labstack.com/), este framework tiene middlewares (son como plugins para extender las funcionalidades a tu servidor web) que te permiten tener variables de sesión, [aquí  un ejemplo](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/session/) de como se implementan sesiones con el framework.

Si te interesa, echo también te permite hacer render de templates (algo simiar como php) para tu web.

También hay otros frameworks similares a echo como [fiber](https://docs.gofiber.io/) o [gin](https://gin-gonic.com/), te permiten hacer casi lo mismo.

Si vas a usar [net/http](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http) para tu web, puedes usar librerías como [go-sessions](https://github.com/kataras/go-sessions).

O también puedes crearlo por tu cuenta, en internet hay algúnos tutoriales para esto, [aquí](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/06.2.html) hay uno.